# How to deal with intrusive identifiers from term.h?

Tags: c, identifier

Testing some code including `term.h`, I've seen some strange errors using usual identifiers such as `tab` or `columns`. It comes from the fact that this header defines a lot of macros. Here are some examples:

```
/* from term.h */

#define columns                        CUR Numbers[0]
#define lines                          CUR Numbers[2]
#define bell                           CUR Strings[1]
#define insert_line                    CUR Strings[53]
#define tab                            CUR Strings[134]
```

However, I didn't find any documentation about these macroconstants. It seems to be shortcuts to access to some members of a `TERMINAL` data structure. Of course, a solution is to `#undef` every identifier used in the source code. But it is very restrictive.

So my question is: why do not prefix the identifiers of `term.h`?
They are often used as local variables in real source code, so it leads to incomprehensible errors.

Comment: I would be tempted do include the result of `awk '$1=="#define"{print "#undef "$2}' /usr/include/term.h`. This file is history, changing it will break lots of compiles and confuse lots of people :-)

Comment: @pbhd: I get, among other things, `#undef tcsetattr(fd,`, which is a syntax error. You'd need to use a regexp to match the identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to deal with the identifier clash:

1. Change the identifiers in `term.h`
2. Change the identifiers in *your* code

The first is a no-no for reasons I hopefully need not explain. `term.h` was there long before your code ever formed as a thought in your brain. Thus it is entirely your fault^Wproblem^Wresponsibility to have created clashing identifiers. :-)

Maybe there's another option:

- Don't use/include `term.h` in the first place.

Comment: +1 for "don't include `term.h`". Hardly useful advice for the OP, but so spot on in the "do not use archaic code" category. Mentioning an alternative might legitimize my upvote `;-)`

Comment: Hey, I know it's my fault. However, this identifiers are very often used in source code, so it is a bit restrictive... But I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option, assuming you MUST use term.h is to isolate the inclusion of that file to a particular module, so that your overall code doesn't clash. But as Jens says, it's your task to "not have name clashes". Public header files that belong to the system shouldn't be changed just because you use the same names as those.